# Laravel datatable nested row-details on nested relationships

Tags: laravel, datatable, nested, relationship

I am trying to view laravel datatable with nested row details on nested relationships. Here are the details of what I have done

**Database relationships**

[image: Database relationships]

I want the datatable to view all products on page load, then first level of row detail will show all components of a product. Second level of row detail will show all sub-components from a component.

**This is the current result of my datatable view**

[image: My final datatable view]

As shown in the illustration, the datatable fails to show the rawmaterial name of a sub-component.
Here are my Eloquent models and relationships.

**Product Model**

```
protected $table = 'products';

public function components() {

    return $this->hasMany('App\Component', 'product_id', 'id');

}
```

**Component Model**

```
protected $table = 'components';

public function comp_subcomps() {

    /*The syntax ->with('subcomponents') seems WORKING fine in resulting 
        the second level row detail ( viewing the subcomponents of a component )*/

    return $this->hasMany('App\CompToSubComp', 'component_id', 'id')->with('subcomponents');

}
```

**CompToSubComp Model**

```
protected $table = 'comp_subcomp';

public function subcomponents() {

        /* This syntax ->with('rawmaterials') seems NOT WORKING to 
            get the material name in the second level row detail */

    return $this->belongsTo('App\SubComponent', 'subcomponent_id', 'id')->with('rawmaterials');

}
```

**SubComponent Model**

```
protected $table = 'subcomponents';

public function rawmaterials() {

    return $this->belongsTo('App\Rawmaterial', 'rawmaterial_id', 'id');

}
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
/* On page load */

public function viewTable() {

    $products = Product::select();

    return Datatables::of($products)
        ->addColumn('details_url', function($product) {
            return url('/product/getdetaildata/' . $product->id);
        })->make(true);
}

/* First level row detail ( showing components of a product ) */

public function getDetailsData($id)
{
    $components = Product::find($id)->components();

    return Datatables::of($components)
        ->addColumn('moredetails_url', function($component) {
            return url('/product/getmoredetail/' . $component->id);
        })->make(true);
}

/* Second level row detail ( showing sub-components of a component ) */

public function getMoreDetailsData($id) {

    $compsubcomp = Component::find($id)->comp_subcomps();

    return Datatables::of($compsubcomp )->make(true);
}
```

**JS DATATABLE**

```
/* On load: Its working */

var dt = $('#example').DataTable({
            ...
            "columns": [
                { "data": "id", "name": "id" },
                { "data": "name", "name": "name"}
            ]
        });

/* First level row detail: Its working */

var tabComponent = $('#' + tableId).DataTable({
            ...
            "columns": [
                { "data": "id", "name": "id" },
                { "data": "name", "name": "name" }
            ]
        });

/* Second level: This PROBLEM exists where RAWMATERIAL NAME is not showing */

$('#' + tableId).DataTable({
            ...
            "columns": [
                { "data": "id", "name": "subcomponents.id" },
                { "data": "name", "name": "subcomponents.name" },
                { "data": "rawmaterial_id", "name": "subcomponents.rawmaterial_id" },
                { "data": "subcomponents.rawmaterials.name", "name": "subcomponents.rawmaterials.name" }
            ]
        });
```

How to correctly view the relationship between 'rawmaterials' and 'subcomponents' inside my datatable?

Any help to identify my errors would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like you don't include the rawmaterials in your controller?

Comment: @StuiterSlurf when I called getMoreDetailsData($id) function, it includes ->comp_subcomps() relationship from Component model which also includes ->with('subcomponents') from CompToSubComp model. From there ->with('rawmaterials') automatically gets called? Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Well you can easily check that just do a print of the subcomponents .rawmaterials